# How can I made requests (QgsFeatureRequest) or selections (selectByExpression) from a list of QgsFeature?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select-by-attribute, qgsfeaturerequest, qgsexpression

I've got a processing algorithm that does a request to select some features that correspond to the incorrect filling of the attributes. It reads a JSON file containing a description of expression (ruleName), layer's name, and a list of expressions (allRules), just like below.

```
{
    "ruleName": {
        "layer": {
            "allRules": ["rule 1", "...", "rule n"]
        }
    }
}
```

I must give to the users an option to run the algorithm only on selected features. In this case, the type of object received change from QgsVectorLayer to a list of QgsFeature, therefore, and I'm stuck here because I can't make any requests through QgsFeatureRequest() or selection using the selectByExpression() method, follow the code below.

```py
    def checkedFeatures(self, rules, layerList, onlySelected, returnIterator=True):
        """
        Select features by conditional rules stored in the rules JSON file.
        :param (dict) rules: dictionary from conditional rules;
        :param (QgsVectorLayer) layerList: list from all loaded layers;
        :param (bool) onlySelected: boolean.
        """
        
        failedDict = {}
        for ruleName in rules:
            failedList = []
            for lyr in layerList:
                loadedLyrName = lyr.name()
                if loadedLyrName in rules[ruleName]:
                    allRules = rules[ruleName][loadedLyrName]['allRules']
                    for rule in allRules:
                        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(rule)
                        if onlySelected:
                            selected = lyr.selectedFeatures()
                            # this FOR block below receives a QgsFeature list from lyr.selectedFeatures()
                            # and so I can't make any requests through QgsFeatureRequest()
                            # or selection using the selectByExpression() method
                            for feat in selected: # I cant do the selection here
                                feat.selectByExpression(rule)
                                failedList+=[feat for feat in lyr.selectedFeatures()]
                        else:
                            for feat in lyr.getFeatures(request):
                                failedList.append(feat)
            failedDict[ruleName] = failedList
        return failedDict
```

The question is: how can I made requests or selections from a list of QgsFeature? Am I missing something?

Comment: For your selected features, do not filter the features yourself and instead let that also to the request. But, make sure you prepend an `is_selected() and` to the request's expression. Something like: `QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("is_selected() and {}".format(rule))`.

Comment: Thanks, @Germán Carrillo. It worked, knew it was something simple that I was missing, but now I cant append to the failedList.                                                            
                      ** if onlySelected:
                            request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("is_selected() and {}".format(rule))
                            for feat in lyr.getFeatures(request):
                                failedList.append(feat)**

Comment: Why you cannot append?

Comment: I still couldn't find out. When I'm debugging the debugger jumps from: for feat in lyr.getFeatures(request): to the previous loop without append in the list and without throw any errors :(

Comment: Are we sure we have selected features at this point and that from those selected features, the rule will actually have a match?